# How to stop waitpid from hanging on certain inputs

Tags: c, operating-system

waitpid hangs when the child "crashes" due to double free errors or memory corruption from freeing stack arrays? is there anyway to catch these types of errors?

```
int status;
errno = 0;
pid_t wait_status = waitpid(cpid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
if (wait_status == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to wait for child id %d - error: %s", cpid, strerror(errno));   
    exit(wait_status);
}
if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    pm->process_status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    pm->status_set = true;
    return;
}
else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Child process was terminated by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
    pm->process_status = -1;
}
else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Child process was stopped\n"); 
    pm->process_status = -1;
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown child error\n");
    pm->process_status = -1;
}
```

I want the blocking behavior of waitpid, and this works for all other cases, but when the child crashes due to a memory error as described above, it never exits, or lets waitpid return.

Comment: Waddya mean by ''waitpid()` hangs'?  Does the child exit or not?  Have you investigated WNOHANG?

Comment: waitpid on the parent unlikely to have any impact regardless of whether the child process ended normally or abnormally and it will get the status of the child when it ends. can you show the code how you are calling waitpid().

Answer (score 1):

If waitpid hangs, this means your child has not exited yet. If your parent process has a main loop and you don't want waitpid to hang, call it with the WNOHANG option: `waitpid(pid, &status_var, WNOHANG)`. As soon as waitpid doesn't return 0, your child has exited.

You can then eg. check for the exit cause with `WIFEXITED`, `WIFSIGNALED` and `WCOREDUMP` as described in the man page.

Answer (score 1):

You can be more precise using waitid instead of waitpid and check si_status. Or you can install a signal handler in your childs.